# How to disable Altering Index in DevOps CI/CD?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In our organization, we work on Visual Studio to manage our SQL Server 2016 databases (with Git on DevOps).

When we push our modifications, the Pipeline takes 1 hour to complete the Release in DevOps because it rebuilds the indexes.

How can we disable the rebuilding of the indexes when we push a modification please ?

The exact message in DevOps log is "... Aletring Index [dbo].....".

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do a schema compare against the destination? There's a chance that it's detecting the index needs modifying on every run. If this is the case you should be able to modify the index in your project to match **exactly** what the schema compare shows and then a deployment should be a no-op.

Comment: I've done a schema compare, and I confirm you that there a differences between VS and SQL Server. I've done an update, but it's running from 30 minutes now...

Comment: Did you update the VS side of things to match exactly what was in the diff?

Comment: Yes I've done that. The update is finished now (it tooks 1 hour and 6 minutes to do it). I hope that will resolve my problem. I'll come back in few days to tell you if everything is OK. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, I've done another Schema Compare today, and all the ALTER INDEX came back :(

Comment: There is something that changing that in our scripts. I must do some research.